# conjunctions: tale da / a tal punto da / tale che / a tal punto che

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I’m looking for an explanation of when to use the following conjunctions. How can I decide which is appropriate for a given sentence? Are there also strict grammatical rules that determine when each should be used?

1) “tale da” vs “a tale punto da” (two sentence clauses with the same subject)

2) “tale che” vs “a tal punto che” (two sentence clauses with different subjects)

3)”così tanto da” vs “così tanto che”

Comment: “così”, not “cosi” (I am not correcting the question so that the OP may notice this).

Comment: What do you mean with "two clauses with the same subject"? I am not sure I have seen "tale da" used in that case.

Comment: "L'esplosione era tale da radere al suolo gli edifici nel raggio di 20 kilometri."

Comment: Ti sei risposto da solo, @kiamlaluno? Oppure non ho capito il tuo dubbio.

Comment: @DaG "Two clauses with the same subject"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: “L'esplosione” is the subject of both “era tale” and the implicit clause “radere al suolo gli edifici”; as opposed to “l'esplosione era tale che tremò tutta la città”, where the second clause's subject is “la città”, not “l'esplosione”.

Answer (score 1):

1) and 2)

First it's very common use the truncated form before a consonant if you use "A **tal** punto"

Anyway **A tal punto da / a tal punto che** have the same meaning of **tale da / tale che** except that they assume there's an imaginary point to be reached and reaching that point cause consequences. It's almost strengthen what you mean. But it's very hard tell when you have to use one or the other way: sometimes you can use both, sometimes you can't.

Talking by (funny) example

> La casa è rossa **a tal punto che** sembra una fragola
>
> The house is so red that seems a strawberry

but it sounds bad saying

> La casa è rossa **tale che** sembra una fragola
>
> The house is so red that seems a strawberry

Using "a tal punto" means that the house is so red which looks almost like a strawberry: if it wasn't so red, it'd look like a house.

3)

In "Così tanto che/da" but also in the 1) and 2) examples **che** and **da** are proposition consecutive and introduce subordinate clauses.
**Che** uses verbs conjugated to the subject. **Da** uses infinitive verbs.

> La casa è rossa a tal punto che **sembra** una fragola
>
> La casa è rossa a tal punto da **sembrare** una fragola

Hope this helps you.. But I'm not an italian teacher